# how to display VisualStudio-like vertical indentation lines in Atom?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, atom-editor

is there any way to adjust preferences in [Atom](https://atom.io/) to display such vertical indentation lines like [Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) does by default?

- [Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQghK.png)
- [Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X156I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn on the indentation guides in Atom, under the "Editor" tab in the settings, find the "Show Indent Guide" option and enable it:

[image: Show Indent Guide]

Comment: jeez, so obvious (I wonder how I managed to not see this). thx for pointing me into the right direction